# MySQL global parameter is reset after reboot

Tags: sql, mysql, database, global-variables, system-variable

So I run the command `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;` in MySQL to change permissions for necessary database function, yet I have realized that this is not preserved when a server is rebooted. After reboot is is once again set to 0/OFF I can't seem to find much on why this is or how to set it permanently.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;`

Use:

```
set persist log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set global variable in config file. `SET GLOBAL` works only in current run.

Answer (score 0):

You can persist [log_bin_trust_function_creators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) (global variable) to be `ON` with the SQL below so that `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is not reset after restarting MySQL. *The change of `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is immediately applied just after running the SQL below and `ON`(`1`) is available for `log_bin_trust_function_creators` and `log_bin_trust_function_creators` session variable doesn't exists and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html) explains how to persist global variables:

```sql
SET PERSIST log_bin_trust_function_creators = ON;
```

Or:

```sql
SET PERSIST log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@PERSIST.log_bin_trust_function_creators = ON;
```

Or:

```sql
SET @@PERSIST.log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

In addition, you can disable `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to persist with the SQL below. *The SQL below doesn't change `log_bin_trust_function_creators` global variable and [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reset-persist.html) explains how to disable persisted global variables:

```sql
RESET PERSIST log_bin_trust_function_creators;
```

And, you can show `log_bin_trust_function_creators` persisted variable with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-persisted-variables-table.html) explains `persisted_variables` table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.persisted_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'log_bin_trust_function_creators';
```